# Kibana, anonymous access, dashboards only

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, anonymous-access

I'm looking for the correct way to give users anonymous access to a Kibana dashboard, but at the same time preventing them from having access to other Kibana features.
I read that the role kibana_dashboard_only_user is now deprecated (I'm on 7.6.2), and that I have to give anonymous users the cluster monitor privilege, so I tried creating a role that has:

- cluster monitor privilege
- read and view-metadata access to the index concerned
- dashbaord read privilege on global spaces

but is doesn't work: I get the following error:

> [security_exception] action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized
>   for user [anonymous_user]

then I tried adding the read rights on the indices .kibana*. It worked, but all the Kibana features are available, not only the dashboards.

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/anonymous-access.html from the Kibana docs?

Comment: @NathanReese : of course I did. That page (which - I believe - belongs to ES docs, not to Kibana docs) explains how to configure Elasticsearch so to allow anonymous access, and that's exactly what I did. My point is about HOW should I configure the roles (the "role1" and "role2" in the page) in order to give to anonymous users the right to see dashboards, and nothing else.

Comment: @Flatline1963, have you been able to solve it or found a workaround yet?

Comment: No, I unfortunately  haven't.

Comment: I've done the same, and apparently the same outcome. I have to try the Role Mapping feature, but looks like this stack is evolving so that anonymous access is not allowed. A pity